# Non Instrumentation Tests for Room Database

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-room

I'm writing tests (*not* instrumentation tests) for the service layer. I'd like to use the actual DAO layer instead of mocks as this makes service layer tests more functional (IMHO). I know how to create an in-memory room db for an instrumentation test:

```
val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
```

However, this won't work in the other tests as the call to `getApplicationContext` makes a call to the `InstrumentationRegistry` which won't work in non-instrumentation tests. I realize that the room tests *should* be instrumentation tests; they are. All DAO tests are instrumentation tests which aim to test out the queries which have been written. I also realize that these aren't technically unit tests; I'm okay with that. In my experience, service layer tests which do not mock the repository layer are less brittle than those which do. Anyway, my question is - how can I accomplish this goal? Is there a way to retrieve the application context without instrumentation? Is there a room db stand-in that doesn't require the application context? Or do I need to implement another version of the DAO classes for the tests?

Answer (score 3):

robolectric will allow you to run this kind of test.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [27])
class Db {
    private lateinit var db: AppDatabase
    private lateinit var myDao: myDaoType

    @Before
    fun createDB() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        myDao = db.myDao()
    }

    @After
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }
}
```